# Given the spring constant & maximum kinetic energy; length of spring extension?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator

I need to understand the following question before i right my exam tomorrow.

A body attached to a spring with spring constant  100 N/m executes simple harmonic motion. The maximum kinetiv energy of the body is 2J. Calculate the spring extension (in m) when its potential energy is equal to the kinetic energy.

I understand the concept of total mechanical energy, i just think im missing something small thats got to do with springs in order to calculate this.

Answer (score 1):

Write down the potential and kinetic energy as a function of position. When the spring is in the middle of the motion, all is kinetic. When it is at the extreme of the range, all is potential. Somewhere between these two extremes, the potential and kinetic energies will be the same; their sum should always be constant (when there is no loss).

Recall that

$$KE = \frac12 m v^2\\
PE = \frac12 k x^2$$

where $k$ is the spring constant, $x$ is the displacement, $m$ is the mass and $v$ is the velocity.

In this case - if max kinetic energy = 2J then potential energy = 1J when it is equal to the kinetic energy. Then you use the PE equation above to find the extension.

Comment: Awsome thanks alot ! this clarifys things up alot more for me